# ejbdeploy issue in IBM was8.5 version

Tags: websphere

When we try to use ejbdeploy.sh to for ejb jars getting below exception in IBM WAS 8.5 version.

```
$TEST.jar Error executing deployment: org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException. Error is Plug-in com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy was unable to load class com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.batch.plugin.BatchExtension..
$TEST.jar org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy was unable to load class com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.batch.plugin.BatchExtension.
$TEST.jar         at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.throwException(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:194)
$TEST.jar         at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:176)
```

Note: every time it is failing with different jars.

Comment: Perhaps this IBM Technote can help: [EJBDeploy command Exceptions on WebSphere Application Server and Eclipse OSGI cache purge issues](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21382867). There are several cases and possible solutions documented here.

Comment: thoses solutions provided in the attached link which didnt wokred out.